# Python Click: How to print full help details on usage error?

Tags: python, python-click

I'm using python click for my CLI. When I pass in the wrong set of arguments or flags, a usage message pops up. However, when I use the `--help` flag a more detailed usage message pops up with a list of all options and arguments. Is there a way to change the default behavior so that a usage error prints the full detailed help?

For example, a missing argument prints

```
mycli foo
Usage: mycli foo [OPTIONS] MY_ARG

Error: Missing argument "my_arg".
```

But adding `--help` prints

```
mycli foo --help
Usage: mycli foo [OPTIONS] MY_ARG

  Long and useful description of the command and stuff.

Options:
  -h, --help  Show this message and exit.
```

The command is implemented roughly like so

```
@click.group()
@click.pass_context
def cli(ctx):
    ctx.obj = {}

@cli.command()
@click.argument('my_arg')
@click.pass_context
@report_errors
def foo(ctx, my_arg):
  # some stuff here
```

Comment: This would be more answerable if you were to give an example showing how you are building your commands.  There are multiple ways to build the above and they will have slightly different solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it could be done by monkey-patching `UsageError`

```
import click
from click.exceptions import UsageError
from click._compat import get_text_stderr
from click.utils import echo


def _show_usage_error(self, file=None):
    if file is None:
        file = get_text_stderr()
    color = None
    if self.ctx is not None:
        color = self.ctx.color
        echo(self.ctx.get_help() + '\n', file=file, color=color)
    echo('Error: %s' % self.format_message(), file=file, color=color)


UsageError.show = _show_usage_error


@click.group()
@click.pass_context
def cli(ctx):
    ctx.obj = {}

@cli.command()
@click.argument('my_arg')
@click.pass_context
@report_errors
def foo(ctx, my_arg):
  # some stuff here
```